# Algorithm for avoiding name collision

Tags: algorithm, stl

I have a collection of objects in an STL vector that are sorted on a member of those objects. Let’s say for the sake of simplicity that this vector is as follows, sorted on integer “string” values:

[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]

I want to be able to process this collection in the following ways:

1. Determine how many of each there are so that they can be renamed to

[1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2, 3-1, 3-2, 4-1, 4-2, 4-3, 4-4, 5]

I want to append a unique item to similarly named items, while leaving single items as they are. It's important that these values are appended in the order that the elements appear in the collection.

2. Increment or decrement their values by a certain amount without causing conflicts with existing elements. I’m pretty sure I have to do this from highest to lowest when incrementing the values because I’ll have to change [5] to [6], then [4-1] to [5-1] before changing [3-1] to [4-1] (since [4-1] will no longer exist at that point). Going from low to high during a decrement operation would be fine since changing [1-1] to [0-1] wouldn’t cause a conflict, but going from low to high during an increment like changing [3-1] to [4-1] would cause a conflict because I’m not sure how I can tell that [4-1] already exists if I haven’t gotten to it yet.
3. Add items from external sources and rerun the process such that if I add

[2, 3, 5]

Their values become

[2-2] and changing the existing [2] to [2-1]. The same occurs for [5].
[3] becomes [3-3] because everything up to [3-2] already exists.

This is perhaps an oversimplified explanation of my goal—to rename digital photos from names like DSC01234.JPG to 2019-08-21 12.34.56.JPG, which is the EXIF date found it the image. I have to be mindful of:

1. adding “ (01)”, “ (02)”, etc. to images that are taken in rapid succession (because their times will be essentially the same)
2. ensuring that 2019-08-21 13.34.56.JPG doesn’t already exist before adding an hour to 2019-08-21 12.34.56.JPG (ie: renaming a bunch of images to dates before running it again with an option to add an hour because I forgot to change the date/time in camera on the date that DST changed). This was my rationale in thinking that processing needed to be from high to low so that I know 13.34.56 will already be changed to 14.34.56 before 12.34.56 is changed to 13.34.56.
3. changing 2019-08-21 12.34.56.JPG to 2019-08-21 12.34.56 (01).JPG before changing DSC05678.JPG that I copied to the folder from another SD card after the first run because its EXIF date is also 2019-08-21 12.34.56 and thus needs to change to 2019-08-21 12.34.56 (02).JPG, with continued use of “ (03)”, “ (04)”, etc. if those images happen to be taken in rapid succession or from yet more added sources.

I hope this isn’t too confusing to understand, but please ask any questions for clarification. I’m not looking for C++ specific code as much as an algorithm that would handle these cases. What I’m doing now is iterating through the vector to find all the [3] with an iterator range before renaming them, then erasing everything from the vector up to the first [4] because that’s the one that told me there were no more [3] but it still needs to be changed. I’m thinking there has to be a better way. Having the ability to rename a file to a date with a time adjustment at the same time would be ideal.

My STL knowledge isn’t expert by any means, so if there’s something better than a vector that I can use, let me know

TIA. I apologize if something similar has been asked elsewhere so please direct me to that question/answer if that's the case.

Update:

Let’s say I have 2 SD cards with the DSC images taken at the listed time and I want to rename the files based on those dates. The file names with “(01)”, etc. are images that were shot as a burst and just happened to be recorded at the same time.

I initially copy the contents of SD 1 to my computer and run my naming process.

SD 1:

DSC00001.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:15 named to 2019-08-11 09.12.15.JPG

DSC00002.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:19 named to 2019-08-11 09.12.19 (01).JPG

DSC00003.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:19 named to 2019-08-11 09.12.19 (02).JPG

DSC00004.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:19 named to 2019-08-11 09.12.19 (03).JPG

DSC00005.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:31 named to 2019-08-11 09.12.31 (01).JPG

DSC00006.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:31 named to 2019-08-11 09.12.31 (02).JPG

DSC00007.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 10:12:15 named to 2019-08-11 10.12.15.JPG

DSC00008.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 11:12:15 named to 2019-08-11 11.12.15.JPG

If I add SD 2 after processing SD 1, I copy its contents to my working folder and rerun the naming process on everything. SD 2 has these files that are renamed in such a way that DSC00101.JPG becomes 2019-08-11 09.12:15 (02).JPG because 2019-08-11 09.12.15.JPG already exists, which itself must be renamed to 2019-08-11 09.12.15 (01).JPG. DSC00102.JPG becomes 09.12:31 (03).JPG because 09.12:31 (01).JPG and 09.12:31 (02).JPG already exist so I use the next highest number.

SD 2:

DSC00101.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:15 named to 2019-08-11 09.12:15 (02).JPG

DSC00102.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 09:12:31 named to 2019-08-11 09.12:31 (03).JPG

DSC00103.JPG taken at 2019-08-11 11:15:18 named to 2019-08-11 11.15.18.JPG

I then realize I’ve forgotten to set my camera time for DST. So, I add an option to add an hour to everything and rerun the process again. But if I process the list in time order from earliest to latest, I will run into a problem in renaming 2019-08-11 10.12.15.JPG to 2019-08-11 11.12.15.JPG because the latter exists, and I haven’t gotten to it yet. So, I thought that in cases where I need to add time, I’ll just process them from latest to earliest times because no later file will exist. I can run from earliest to latest when subtracting time because no earlier file will exist.

Basically, I want to rename images from their default names to the date and time found in the EXIF data. I need to be mindful of images taken in burst having the same taken time so that I can make the name unique with a sequence number like “(01)” in the order they were actually taken, add sequence numbers to images that require them if they were added to the working folder after an initial run and regardless if a sequence with that time exists or not, and guard against naming conflicts where adding or subtracting time produces a new name that’s the same as a file I haven’t gotten to yet in the processing order.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking about. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm looking for the best approach on renaming files that don't cause name conflicts with those that exist and appending some kind of tag to those where a sequence of files having the same name could still be different.

Comment: why can´t you just use a map<key, vector<values>> to group them by same values. When you add something to it, if its the first element just keep same name. If its second, name it value + '-2' and rename first to value + '-1'. For any other its value + '-' + list.length().

Comment: I'm also confused.  In some places, you talk about simply adding a sequential suffix to each file with a conflicting name.  In another, you fret over adjusting values within the original labeling (no suffix).

Comment: Most of what you describe can be handled with simple, sequential mapping, or a sequential suffix.  I don't see where you need a custom algorithm to solve the problem of uniqueness.

Comment: Please show an example of input and required output. That would help with the confusion. Then explain the rules that got you from input to output.

Comment: I've added an update that I hope clarifies things for everyone. Your input is appreciated.

Comment: I used juvian's approach by creating a map of files keyed on time values. When the map is complete, I can rename the files and add sequence numbers as required. It actually simplified the code as I don't have to do any more custom checking beyond the order of processing for adding or subtracting time.

I consider this question solved. Thank you for your input.